# Java 8 : Compare 2 Collections and formulate a separate collection using another property

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have a very simple code snippet that I would like to be converted to Java 8's list streaming methods. Any help would be really appreciated.

I have 2 collections one is a Set of String and other a list of a simple POJO which itself consists a list of string. Below is the relevant code:

POJO sample

```
public class SimplePojo {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private List<String> desiredStringList;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<String> getDesiredStringList() {
        return desiredStringList;
    }

    public void setDesiredStringList(List<String> desiredStringList) {
        this.desiredStringList= desiredStringList;
    }

}
```

Comparison that I am wishing to transform

```
Set<String> someStrings // Contains a list of strings that needs to be compared

List<SimplePojo> pojoObjectList // Contains list of SimplePojo objects 

/* Each of someStrings need to be compared to each of SimplePojo.name property
    and corresponding actions which is List object needs to be populated as a separate list
    Below is the code snippet which has a mixture of Java 8 stream and regular For-Each loop
*/
Set<String> desiredStrings = new HashSet<String>();

for(String s : someStrings) {
    List<String> interimDesiredStrings =  pojoObjectList.stream()
                                            .filter(o -> StringUtils.equals(s, o.getName()))
                                            .flatMap(o -> o.getDesiredStringList().stream())
                                            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    desiredStrings.addAll(interimDesiredStrings);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this perfectly demonstrates, where overusing third-party utility functions leads to.

You are using `StringUtils.equals` and there’s no sign of whether this is the Apache Commons version or the Spring version (or yet another library having such a function). Or why you are using this special method.

In the Apache case, it would be justified, if it is at least version 3 and `getName()` is declared to return `CharSequence`, in the Spring case, it’s not justified at all. Besides supporting `CharSequence` in the Apache case, both variants merely exist to handle `null` silently, but if handling `null` really is your concern, using the standard [`Objects.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) instead would immediately clarify the intention. Perhaps, even `null` isn’t you concern.

The reason, why this is so important, is that your task can be easily implemented using standard equality semantics

```
Set<String> desiredStrings = pojoObjectList.stream()
    .filter(o -> someStrings.contains(o.getName()))
    .flatMap(o -> o.getDesiredStringList().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Assuming that `someStrings` refers to a `Set` with a reasonable lookup efficiency (as with most `Set` implementations), this will be significantly more efficient than your nested iterations.

Note that if the `Set` referenced by `someStrings` does not support `null`, it would imply that a `null` name is not “desired”, hence, if `getName()` could return `null`, changing the filter to

```
    .filter(o -> o.getName()!=null && someStrings.contains(o.getName()))
```

would solve this in a clear way.

Comment: Yes I was using Apache Lang3's StringUtils, and I put that in to handle null check silently as you have stated, but what I missed is what you and others have stated, so thanks for pointing out the error. 
Although everybody else has provided a same/similar solution, i am going to accept this as the correct answer given the explanation so that others can benefit.
Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

Why not go over the list of objects once and just check if the name is in the set of names to match?

```
Set<String> desiredStrings = pojoObjectList.stream()
    .filter(o -> someStrings.contains(o.getName()))
    .flatMap(o -> o.getDesiredStringList().stream())
    .collect(toSet());
```

Comment: You are right, thanks!! But I am accepting Holger's answer as it provides more explanation and the standard practices he suggested